# Digital Signature and Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, digital-signature

This question is related to SharePoint Online/Office 365. How can I digitally sign a document in SharePoint? Is this something which SharePoint can do or do I need to use some third party solutions.

As far as I understand, digital signature is actually done by Office client such as Word etc. For that you need to have certificate installed on PC and then in MS Word you can open that document and sign digitally.

I assume the same can be done in Office 365 i.e. I can open Word web view and digitally sign document!?

Can this be done in SharePoint i.e. user uploads document in a library and it is digitally signed by SharePoint (using some kind of 3rd party plugin). So instead of having certificate installed on each PC, it will reside on SharePoint.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

We are not able to use digital signature directly in Office Online in SharePoint Online.

You need to use third-party tool which will integrate with SharePoint Online.

Comment: What about Collect Signatures workflow which works with SharePoint Online?  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/all-about-collect-signatures-workflows-90fcf6a9-4839-4138-a1fb-682d6d46a872

Answer (score 0):

As Hellofiona_MSFT mentioned, that's not available in SharePoint online.

but you can use a third party such as Adobe Sign which use Cloud Signature, and has integration support for sharePoint.

[Adobe Sign for SharePoint](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/business/integrations/microsoft-sharepoint.html)

Comment: This Adobe Sign looks like e-signature and not digital signature which I am looking for.